# Sie erzählt mir von "ihrem/ihren" neuen Job

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence and my German skills failed me.

> Sie erzählt mir von "*ihrem/ihren*" "*neuen/neuem*" Job.

What is correct:
"ihrem oder ihren" and why?

"neuen oder neuem" and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in your grammar book? What did it say about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *von*, you use dative.

Thus it is:

> Sie erzählt mir von *ihrem neuen* Job.

It's not a problem that *mir* is dative as well because *mir* does not have a preposition in front but *ihrem neuen Job* does. (There are even cases where the same case is used multiple times in the same sentence without prepositions)

With dative and masculine/neuter nouns, you use the -m form with the first article/adjective and the -n form with every following article/adjective.